# rsync on AIX gives popt The module has an invalid magic number error

Tags: rsync, aix, shared-library

```
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] rsync -avz --delete ...
Could not load program rsync:
    Dependent module /opt/freeware/lib/libpopt.a(libpopt.so.0) could not be loaded.
    The module has an invalid magic number.
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at io.c(600) [sender=3.0.6]
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] 
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] oslevel -s
6100-09-06-1543
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] rpm -qa | egrep -i 'popt|rsync'
popt-1.16-1
rsync-3.0.6-1
[SERVER:root:/home/user:]
```

**Question**: Why does rsync gives the above error message? What could the problem be?

UPDATE:

```
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] file /opt/freeware/lib/libpopt.a*
/opt/freeware/lib/libpopt.a: archive (big format)
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] 
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] getconf KERNEL_BITMODE
64
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] 
[SERVER:root:/home/user:] ar t /opt/freeware/lib/libpopt.a
libpopt.so.0
[SERVER:root:/home/user:]
```

Comment: What does `file /opt/freeware/lib/libpopt.a*` give you?  (Add the output to your question, not as a comment, thanks)

Comment: @EightBitTony : I updated

Comment: Archives can have both 32bit and 64bit. Use 'ar t libpopt.a' to look inside

Comment: it only gaved back libpopt.so.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: a few popt library file was overwritten by someone on the TARGET side. re-installed popt on target side.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this when 64bit libraries are installed on 32bit kernels and vice versa.

Comment: I know how to check that popt is 32 or 64bit, but how about rsync?

Comment: `file $(which rsync)` should help with that. It would help more if you could mention which packages where installed, or provide the output of `rpm -qa --qf="%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}-%{ARCH} \n" | grep -E "rsync|popt"`